# How can i automatically run a GWT Compile in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compilation, eclipse-plugin

I would like to write an eclipse plug-in which automatically execute an GWT Compile on a certain Java project in my current workspace. 
The manual steps would be: right click on the project -> Google -> GWT Compile ->Compile.
Does anyone knows how the code for the steps would look like in java?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why do you need such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SuperDevMode, the superdevmode launch a code server and call the url :

```
http://localhost:9876/recompile/moduleName
```

This will recompile the module.

Or you can look at the SuperDevMode Source to see how to call the compiler.
https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/CodeServer.java